# Jest + React Testing Library: Portals are not being cleaned up

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

As far as I understand it, React Testing Library cleans up your DOM after every test automatically (at least when you're using Jest).

This works for whatever is rendered inside my `root` node, but anything that's been rendered outside `root` with Portals is not getting cleaned up and being persisted across tests.

Unfortunately some of my components depend on a `modal` component that renders with a portal, so once this component has been opened, I have no way to remove it from the DOM in subsequent tests.

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue with `ant-design`, I found 2 solutions.

### Solution #1, add an additional option `container: document.body` when calling `render` (works with warnings, NOT encouraged by `testing-library`)

```
render(<CreateOrEditAvailability isEdit={false} />, { initialState, container: document.body });
```

Warnings:

- No. 1

```
Warning: render(...): Replacing React-rendered children with a new root component. If you intended to update the children of this node, you should instead have the existing children update their state and render the new components instead of calling ReactDOM.render.

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:88:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:5)
      at topLevelUpdateWarnings (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24664:7)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24733:5)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24840:10)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:99:25
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21856:12)
```

- No. 2

```
Warning: render(): Rendering components directly into document.body is discouraged, since its children are often manipulated by third-party scripts and browser extensions. This may lead to subtle reconciliation issues. Try rendering into a container element created for your app.

      at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:88:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:5)
      at topLevelUpdateWarnings (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24668:7)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24733:5)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24840:10)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:99:25
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21856:12)
```

### Solution #2, remove modals manually with `removeChild` in `afterEach`

```js
afterEach(() => {
    const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.ant-modal-wrap');
    modals.forEach((modal) => modal.parentNode.removeChild(modal));
});

test('blah blah', () => {
    render(<CreateOrEditAvailability isEdit={false} />, { initialState });
    ...
});
```

Comment: I am able to remove the Modal from the DOM by doing `screen.debug()`, but it seems like it breaks the subsequent tests from creating the future Modal. And I use Microsoft Fluent-UI, and not ant-design. Still couldn't find another solution that works for general cases.

Comment: @kelvien Different UI frameworks have different Modal component implementations, especially where to mount the Modals (document.body or somewhere else), there's no general solution b/c UI frameworks don't follow a general standard for Modal component.

Comment: Found the comment where Kent C Dodds doesn't recommend using {container: document.body} https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/62#issuecomment-388395307